# User Management through Core Services

Tags: 2011, core-service

We can access SDL Tridion User details through the `UserData` object, but 
can we also create Users and assign Roles using Core Services in 2011?

Comment: Yes - of course you can. If you have tried this and had trouble, please let us know what you tried and what the problems were.

Answer (score 8):

Of course you can:

```
var user = (UserData) ClientAdmin.GetDefaultData(ItemType.User, null, new ReadOptions());
user.Title = "domain\\user";
user.Description = "My new user";

user.GroupMemberships = new[]
{
    new GroupMembershipData
    {
        Group = new LinkToGroupData {IdRef = groupId},
        Scope = new[]
        {
            new LinkWithIsEditableToRepositoryData { IdRef = publication1Id },
            new LinkWithIsEditableToRepositoryData { IdRef = publication2Id },
        }
    },
};
user = (UserData) ClientAdmin.Create(user, new ReadOptions());
```